# sumar forms o sumar id en js

Tags: javascript, formularios, radiobutton

Estos form entregan un la suma de los valores en pantalla instantáneo pero quiero saber como puedo sumar darle una clase a cada form y después sumar alguno de ellos por ejemplo  form1 +form2 pero no el form 3, para después acumular ese valor quizás en un local storage y mostrarlos en otro pagina ,porque lo que quiero hacer es que se sumen los formularios de manera automática y los muestre en la misma pagina  y sumar alguno de ellos que coincidan con algún tipo de etiqueta (clase , group , id ,etc) y mostrarlos en una pagina final (son 8 de de formularios y una que muestra los resultados) de momento la suma total de cada pagina se guarda en un local storage . plz ayuda es lo unico que me falta hacer para terminar mi primera mini aplicación en js , dejare un fragmento del codigo

```
 form 1
    <form name="form1" id="form1" runat="server" class="form-control text-center">
                                
        <input id="rdo_av" type="radio" value="5" name="price" onclick="DisplayPrice2(this.value);">   CS 
        <input id="rdo_av" type="radio" value="4" name="price" onclick="DisplayPrice2(this.value);">   F
          
    </form>



form 2
                  
    <form name="form2" id="form2" runat="server" class="form-control text-center">
                            
        <input id="rdo_av" type="radio" value="5" name="price2" onclick="DisplayPrice2(this.value);">   CS 
        <input id="rdo_av" type="radio" value="4" name="price2" onclick="DisplayPrice2(this.value);">   F
      
         </form>

form 3

    <form name="form3" id="form3" runat="server" class="form-control text-center">
                            
        <input id="rdo_ss" type="radio" value="5" name="price3" onclick="DisplayPrice2(this.value);">   CS 
        <input id="rdo_ss" type="radio" value="4" name="price3" onclick="DisplayPrice2(this.value);">   F
  </form>

<div >
resutado 
        <input type="text" name="totalSum2" id="totalSum2" value="" size="10" readonly="readonly" class="form-control">
        <br>
        
    </div>

el js es 

<script>
function DisplayPrice2() {
    var val1 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < document.form1.price.length; i++) {
        if (document.form1.price[i].checked == true) {
            val1 = document.form1.price[i].value;
           
        }
    }

    var val2 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < document.form2.price2.length; i++) {
        if (document.form2.price2[i].checked == true) {
            val2 = document.form2.price2[i].value;
        }
    }

    var val3 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < document.form3.price3.length; i++) {
        if (document.form3.price3[i].checked == true) {
            val3 = document.form3.price3[i].value;
        }
    }





var sum2 = parseInt(val1) + parseInt(val2) + parseInt(val3);
    document.getElementById('totalSum2').value = sum2;
 
   
}
 </script>
```

Comment: No repitas **ids** aunque te parezca que es correcto en botones de radio, ni mucho menos, es incorrecto siempre. Los botones de radio pueden compartir **name** pero no **ids**.  Tu código necesita cambiar los ids por clases, que sí se pueden repetir y también se pueden manejar fácilmente con javascript para lograr lo que quieres. Arregla eso, reformula la pregunta (la puedes [edit] para modificarla) y miraré de ayudarte, pues ahora veo demasiados cambios que realizar para responder bien.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario creo que solo con eso me ayudas, se podria hacer con un form group o algo asi ?